# Como utilizar el valor de una variable global al cambiar de vista en javascrip y php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, css

Este es el código del controlador donde se debe recibir el id, pero no llega, por favor si necesitan otro código para poder ayudarme me dicen para editar la pregunta.

```html
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    require_once '../../modelo/modelo_compras_detalle.php';
    $MC = new Modelo_Compras_Detalle();
    $id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['id'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
    $consulta = $MC->leer_compras_detalle($id);
    echo json_encode($consulta);
}else{
    echo 'no hay id';
}
```

Es un sistema de control de inventarios, estoy trabajando en php y javascript, lo que sucede es que queria tomar el id de un registro de un Datatable.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
en esta ventana al darle click en el boton azul, se abre el detalle de la compra en especifico pero en otra ventana y no se pasa el id que deberia llegar por lo que no me muestra datos y la variable sale como undefined.

aqui adjunto el codigo javascript disculpen si no pongo todo lo necesario, no se usar esta plataforma.

```js
var data_id;


$("#tabla-compras").on('click', '#detalles', function () {
    var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
    if (table.row(this).child.isShown()) {
        var data = table.row(this).data();
    }
    data_id = data.id;

});

function listar_compras_detalle() {
    console.log(data_id);
    table = $("#tabla-compras-detalle").DataTable({
        "ordering": false,
        "paging": true,
        "select": false,
        "searching": { "regex": true },
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        "pageLength": 10,
        "destroy": true,
        "async": false,
        "processing": true,
        "ajax": {
            url: "/Tienda/controlador/Compras_Detalle/controlador_compras_detalle.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: data_id,
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "nombre" },
            { "data": "medida_producto" },
            { "data": "cantidad" },
            { "data": "precio" },
            { "data": "total" }],

        language: {
            url: '/Tienda/Plantilla/plugins/DataTables/es-ar.json'
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Probaste en tu controlador si esta recibiendo el POST? en tu PHP puedes poner un stop y revisar si esta llegando, pueden imprimir el array $_POST y detener el script para ver si esta ahi tu id, segun lo que veo, es el unico parametro que usa tu controlador

Comment: disculpa como hago eso, no tengo experiencia con esto.

Comment: Acabo e probar y no llega el id al controlador, lo que yo creo es que al cambiar de pagina o vista la variable global por alguna razon no mantiene su valor y llega vacio, porque si no cambio de vista con un console.log verifique que si toma el id

Comment: Lo que no veo tampoco es donde se inicializa tu funcion de JS que ejecuta el AJAX

Comment: Hola. En este caso, hace falta el código php para ver cómo se genera la tabla e indicarte que puntos específicos corregir para que los ids puedan ser pasados luego a javascript y retornados correctamente. Aprovecho pada darte la bienvenida a [es.so]. Por favor haz el [tour] y consulta [ask] para entender las necesidades de las preguntas para que generen respuestas y luego regresa a [edit] y haz los cambios necesarios.

Comment: puse el codigo php del controlador, miren me funciona todo pero si lo cargo en un contenedor sin recargar ni cambiar de vista, ahi si obtiene el id de la tabla compras, pero como dije si lo quiero mostrar en otra vista no funciona.

Comment: Al cargar la nueva vista te aparece el mensaje 'no hay id' o no muestra nada?

Comment: exacto muestra no hay id

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código con el que muestras los botones y asignas el evento _onclick_.